# AjaxContent cannot be loaded in any browsers.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Why is it my ajaxContent not loaded? It was working before I created the text files and the ajax function. Now it cannot be loaded in Chrome or Firefox. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My website</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

function ajax(url) {
    $("#ajaxContent").load(url);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ajax('Aboutus.txt');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Aboutus.txt')">About us</a></li>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Menu.txt')">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Menu.txt')">Events</a></li>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Menu.txt')">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Menu.txt')">Booking</a></li>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Menu.txt')">Shop</a></li>
<li><a href onClick="ajax('Menu.txt')">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<article id="ajaxContent"></article>
<footer>
&copy; 2016
</footer>
</div><!-- .wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console, for example 404?

Comment: And why there's a `<link>` tag inside `<script>`...?

Comment: The links are just libraries.

Comment: On Dreamweaver it seems just fine but when I open the file in any browser the <div wrapper> doesn't stretch to let the content to show.

Comment: Move your link tag outside (above) the script tag as Gothdo noted.

Comment: I did it but still does not load.

Comment: are you loading the html files via a server like IIS or WAMP? ajax calls cannot work if they are loaded via local filesystem

Comment: yes it is local file system but it was working before, how come now it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have a web server (IIS or Apache) installed and serving files. mixture of protocols will never give you the desired results.

you are loading all the assets over `http` or `https` protocol. you need to load all your html files and css files over `http` which requires a web server.

have a look at [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)